# How to replace value in each field until a certain character in each record?

Tags: unix, awk, sed

Each record coming with column names. It is pipe delimited. I have to replace them in each record as shown below:
Input:

```
COMPILES=1|PROPS=inet.timeoutDownload=5000;inet.timeoutIO=5000;inet.timeoutOpen=5000;inet.urlBase=vxml3-elr:7000/CVP/;swirec_language=en-US|SCPU=30828
```

Output:

```
1|inet.timeoutDownload=5000;inet.timeoutIO=5000;inet.timeoutOpen=5000;inet.urlBase=vxml3-elr:7000/CVP/;swirec_language=en-US|30828
```

I was trying the command sed `'s/[^|]*=//g'` to replace all sequences of non-| characters followed by `=` with nothing but in the 2nd column it is printing only last value. Is there a way to replace only 1st instance in each field?

```
1|en-US|30828
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
$ sed 's/\(^\||\)[^=]\+=/\1/g' file
1|inet.timeoutDownload=5000;inet.timeoutIO=5000;inet.timeoutOpen=5000;inet.urlBase=vxml3-elr:7000/CVP/;swirec_language=en-US|30828
```

Explained:

- `s/` replace
- `\(^\||\)[^=]\+=` beginning (`^`) or (`\|`) separator (`|`) and all non-`=`s and a `=`
- `/\1/g` with beginning or separator (`\1`) globally (`g`)

ie. replace `^THIS=` with `^` and `|THIS=` with `|`.

Comment: Your matching `|` at the start of the field is smarter than `sed -r 's/[^=]*=([^|]*)([|]|$)/\1\2/g'`, +1.

Comment: @MullapudiSudhakar Explained the regex.

Comment: @JamesBrown Thanks a lot . When I am using this for  following  record it's replacing " "  with in the data.                                           
  echo "CNTNT=<?xml version='1.0'?><result><interpretation grammar="session:field320753672@field.grammar" confidence="100"><input mode="dtmf">0</input><instance><SWI_literal>0</SWI_literal><value confidence="100">representative</value><SWI_grammarName>session:field320753672@field.grammar</SWI_grammarName><SWI_meaning>{value:representative}</SWI_meaning></instance></interpretation></result>|UCPU=190140" |sed 's/\(^\||\)[^=]\+=/\1/g'

Comment: You need to copy the command like I wrote it. `\(` is not the same as `(`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
awk -v RS='|' -v ORS='|' '{sub("[^.]*=","")}1' input | sed "s|\|$||g"
```

- `RS`, record separator, usually is newline, in this case it changes to `|`, so a record would be `COMPILES=1` or `PROPS=inet.timeoutDownload=5000;inet.timeoutIO=5000;inet.timeoutOpen=5000;inet.urlBase=vxml3-elr:7000/CVP/;swirec_language=en-US`
- `ORS`, output record separator, is also newline, changes to `|`, so when print, the output would be separated by `|`
- `sub("[^.]*=","")` its a lazy regex to replace the first value before `=`, more about it in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49601/how-to-reduce-the-greediness-of-a-regular-expression-in-awk
- `sed "s|\|$||g"` to delete the last `|`

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sub(/[^=]+=/,"",$i)}1' file
```

results with

```
1|inet.timeoutDownload=5000;inet.timeoutIO=5000;inet.timeoutOpen=5000;inet.urlBase=vxml3-elr:7000/CVP/;swirec_language=en-US|30828
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$ cat mullapudi.log
COMPILES=1|PROPS=inet.timeoutDownload=5000;inet.timeoutIO=5000;inet.timeoutOpen=5000;inet.urlBase=vxml3-elr:7000/CVP/;swirec_language=en-US|SCPU=30828

$ perl -F"\|" -ane ' s/^.+?=//g for @F; print join("|",@F) ' mullapudi.log
1|inet.timeoutDownload=5000;inet.timeoutIO=5000;inet.timeoutOpen=5000;inet.urlBase=vxml3-elr:7000/CVP/;swirec_language=en-US|30828
```